# Generating file hashes through pandas dataframe apply creates the same hash for all files

Tags: python, pandas, hash

If have a data frame full of file paths and I want to create hashes for each file

the code looks something like this:

```
def generate_hash(path):
    path = paht['path']
    BLOCK_SIZE = 10485760 
    file_hash = hashlib.sha256() 
    with open(file, 'rb') as f: 
        fb = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE) 
        while len(fb) > 0: 
            file_hash.update(fb) 
            fb = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE) 

    return file_hash.hexdigest() 


df['hash'] = df.apply((generate_hash, axis=1)
```

with this the same hash is generated for each file and the df looks like this:

```
   path           hash
0  /path/file_1   09b85c3f91d4fc5fe88610acad1094d064b253ebfacf26ed2cb16c4e89468504
1  /path/file_2   09b85c3f91d4fc5fe88610acad1094d064b253ebfacf26ed2cb16c4e89468504  
2  /path/file_3   09b85c3f91d4fc5fe88610acad1094d064b253ebfacf26ed2cb16c4e89468504
3  /path/file_4   09b85c3f91d4fc5fe88610acad1094d064b253ebfacf26ed2cb16c4e89468504  
4  /path/file_5   09b85c3f91d4fc5fe88610acad1094d064b253ebfacf26ed2cb16c4e89468504
```

but since they are different files they should not generate the same hash which when I just iterate over the paths in a `for loop` is correctly generated

this code:

```
for file in glob.glob('path/**', recursive=True):
    print(file)
    print(generate_hash(file))
```

generates the expected outcome:

```
/path/file_1  
fdf755afcb1a4a38474ab1f2bca4969eec6e3dac09772559f473c33915b1323d
/path/file_2
957c584f39d2a8938174a9b715b9d67998ebb7ba94619f15e076a5c649714067
/path/file_3 
fab912b026cbd2ba4c507ffa6f996e862133e1db2c705881819fa258eb76bebc
/path/file_4 
d7dc9e575e4e36ed5542e9102044926598b0a600e1e0f59db3993be53518b7e6
/path/file_5
09b85c3f91d4fc5fe88610acad1094d064b253ebfacf26ed2cb16c4e89468504
```

so in the df example each row gets the actual hash of `file_5` what am I missing here?pn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `open(file, 'rb')` with `open(path, 'rb')`, here `path` represent the value of the `path` from the current series `s` passed to the `generate_hash` function.

Use:

```
def generate_hash(s):
    path = s['path']
    BLOCK_SIZE = 10485760 
    file_hash = hashlib.sha256() 
    with open(path, 'rb') as f: 
        fb = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE) 
        while len(fb) > 0: 
            file_hash.update(fb) 
            fb = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE) 

    return file_hash.hexdigest()
```